# Unable to pass value from FragmentOne to FragmentTwo even after setting argument value for destination fragment in navigation

Tags: android, kotlin

FragmentTwo fragment class code:

```
class FragmentTwo : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding : FragmentTwoBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_two, container, false)
        var args = FragmentTwoArgs.fromBundle(arguments)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        inflater?.inflate(R.menu.overflow_menu,menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item!!,findNavController())
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

FragmentOne fragment class code:

```
class FragmentOne : Fragment() {
    var nameValue = "Abhas"

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)
        val binding: FragmentOneBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)
        binding.clickable = this

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(FragmentOneDirections.actionFragmentOneToFragmentTwo())
        }
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

navigation xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentOne">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentOne"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentpractise1.FragmentOne"
        android:label="fragment_one"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_one" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentOne_to_fragmentTwo"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentTwo" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTwo"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentpractise1.FragmentTwo"
        android:label="fragment_two"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_two" >
        <argument
            android:name="nameValue"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentpractise1.AboutFragment"
        android:label="fragment_about"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about" />
</navigation>
```

Now when I am setting args variable in FragmentTwo class, arguments showing error in fromBundle(arguments). I have tried giving argument in setOnclicklistener in FragmentOne while navigating but it's not asking for any kind of value in constructor. I am unable to understand why
arguments in fromBundle(arguments) of FragmentTwo class showing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forget to declare argument inside the action(fragment one).
And you don't send anything from fragment_one.

You should add argument to the action inside the fragment_one in navigation xml :

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_fragmentOne_to_fragmentTwo"
                app:destination="@id/fragmentTwo">
        <argument
            android:name="nameValue"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="default" />
    </action>
```

then re-build the app - another navigation action method will be generated with a string argument.

```
FragmentOneDirections.actionFragmentOneToFragmentTwo(nameValue : String)
```

So you should put the value to this method in fragment one.

You can find detailed documentation by the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args).

Comment: As I know, we need to add argument in destination fragment. You are saying me to add arguments in base fragment. Is it correct? Please enlighten me on this.

Comment: Arguments used within `action` are meant to override the ones declared within `fragment`. [Override a destination argument in an action](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#override_a_destination_argument_in_an_action)